# Reason for making tracks like this? Is this because of some EMC/EMI perspective? This is two layer ESP32 EVB board

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, pcb, power-electronics, esp32

What is exact reason for making this type of tracks? Is it because of some EMC/EMI advantage point or just some design habit?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If someone designed a board with RF and QFP/QFN parts on 2 layers, then EMC (or quality design in general) is the least of their concerns.

Comment: Looks like an attempt at teardrops. Perhaps just personal preference?

Comment: This looks like KiCAD to my eyes, and the KiCAD teardrop plugin broke for quite a while when v6 came out, so it's possible that this was a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

On connectors, it is important that the mechanical stress does not break the copper track. A wider track at the connector is a solution.

Comment: Can you explain this better? I would think stress is mostly bending or tension, both of which are independent of width.

Comment: Even if Tim is right, it is widely believed that fatter tracks are less likely to break at the via/trace connection. So this could be the explanation, even if it is misguided.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't make much sense to me.

Looks like a (failed) attempt to add teardrops.

It could also be a (failed) attempt to improve heat transfer to the pads during manual soldering with a soldering iron. I'm not familiar with the CAD-tool used here. But it doesn't look like the solder mask openings are extending over these fat traces (hence "failed"). Also on the TH pins some fat traces extend towards the second row (maybe not the optimal place to fit the tip of a soldering iron).

Comment: On the thru-holes, it's a crude teardrop, agreed.  On the SMTs... overgeneralization maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it's purposeful.

There are settings in most EDA tools for fanout rules, where the orientation, length and width of traces entering pads can be controlled.  It almost looks like it was used here, but misconfigured.

The thicker sections on the THT pads will serve as teardrops, albeit oddly shaped ones.  Teardrops help to increase the pad size (annular ring) around the trace connection, giving a better chance of a solid connection even if the drill misses its mark significantly (typically within ~0.12mm of center, check your fab's design rules).  Mind, even a full miss (hole drilled through trace) isn't an automatic fail, the plating in the hole still reaches the trace.  But the edge or corner between hole and surface is then smaller (less perimeter), more vulnerable to manufacturing or mechanical errors.  So an annular ring surrounding the pad is preferable.

Such short lengths, and on a 2-layer board besides (or at least no inner planes are shown here), are completely irrelevant for EMI purposes.  Trace lengths of fractional mm only have noticeable effect at 10s of GHz.